# Scaling data for correlation test

Tags: correlation, scales

I have a dataset of variables with different types and units (some are percentages). I was wondering whether scaling data is important before doing a correlation in this case ?
I am using rcorr() from Hmisc package on R.

Comment: Although it's not the question let's flag that variables bounded by 0 and 100%  might be related nonlinearly -- which is a major point of logit and probit models, etc. So Pearson correlation on the original data might not be ideal.

Comment: @NickCox so what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Logit and probit models can be applied to continuous proportions. This is sometimes called fractional regression. Similar in spirit but not in substance is beta  regression. Simpler than either is to underline that Spearman correlation looks for monotonic relationships, so S-curves are fine.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling should not affect correlation calculations since they are scale-adjusted calculations of covariance: $$\text{cor}(X,Y)=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\text{sd}(X)\,\text{sd}(Y)}$$

So it should make no difference whether you do the calculations before or after rescaling.