# Confused by an article on princomp in R

Tags: r, pca

I am reading this article:

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pca-analysis-r

The article says:

We need to center/scale the numeric variables, compute the correlation/covariance matrix and then invoke princomp with that correlation/covariance matrix as the ***first*** argument.

The [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/princomp.html) page for princomp says:

```
     ## Default S3 method:
     princomp(x, cor = FALSE, scores = TRUE, covmat = NULL,
              subset = rep_len(TRUE, nrow(as.matrix(x))), fix_sign = TRUE, ...)

       x: a numeric matrix or data frame which provides the data for
          the principal components analysis.

  covmat: a covariance matrix, or a covariance list as returned by
          ‘cov.wt’ (and ‘cov.mve’ or ‘cov.mcd’ from package ‘MASS’).
          If supplied, this is used rather than the covariance matrix
          of ‘x’.
```

If I understand correctly, we may do one of 2 things.

1. Invoke this function with only ***one*** unnamed argument which will then be understood by the program as the input x. The program will ***automatically*** compute the covariance matrix and then do it's eigen decomposition to compute the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of x which in turn will give us the Principal Components of x.
2. Invoke this function with only one argument which is covmat = the covariance matrix. This will again do an eigen decomposition of this matrix and return the eigenvalues/eignevectors of this matrix ( which is the correlation or covariance matrix of x, because we ***chose*** it to be so).

We cannot:
Compute the correlation / covariance matrix and then invoke the princomp function with this matrix as the only unnamed argument. If we do so the program will think that correlation/covariance matrix as the matrix ***x*** and will internally compute the eigenvalues / eignenvectors of the correlation/covariance matrix of the correlation/covariance mattrix of x.

This will return the PCs of the correlation/covariance matrix and not the principal componenets of ***x***.

Here is a small simulation:

These 2 are ***kind of*** the same:

```
> princomp(mtcars)
Call:
princomp(x = mtcars)

Standard deviations:
     Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3      Comp.4      Comp.5      Comp.6 
134.3827868  37.5472829   3.0226511   1.2860724   0.8922099   0.6530910 
     Comp.7      Comp.8      Comp.9     Comp.10     Comp.11 
  0.3037193   0.2814568   0.2467490   0.2073344   0.1952988 

 11  variables and  32 observations.
> 


> princomp(covmat = cov(mtcars))
Call:
princomp(covmat = cov(mtcars))

Standard deviations:
     Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3      Comp.4      Comp.5      Comp.6 
136.5330479  38.1480776   3.0710166   1.3066508   0.9064862   0.6635411 
     Comp.7      Comp.8      Comp.9     Comp.10     Comp.11 
  0.3085791   0.2859604   0.2506973   0.2106519   0.1984238 

 11  variables and  NA observations.
>
```

This is different to the above 2:

```
> princomp(cov(mtcars))
Call:
princomp(x = cov(mtcars))

Standard deviations:
      Comp.1       Comp.2       Comp.3       Comp.4       Comp.5       Comp.6 
5.168233e+03 4.334259e+02 2.724862e+00 5.090709e-01 2.042575e-01 1.263206e-01 
      Comp.7       Comp.8       Comp.9      Comp.10      Comp.11 
2.649914e-02 2.136515e-02 1.893399e-02 1.273819e-02 0.000000e+00 

 11  variables and  11 observations.
>
```

Also, notice how the program above says:

```
princomp(x = cov(mtcars))
```

Do I misunderstand?

Note : I did not scale the variables like the author in the above mentioned page did and ***perhaps*** that made a difference. So I did the following experiment to test if that makes a difference.

Once again, the first 2 seem similar while the third seems different.

````
> princomp(scale(mtcars))
Call:
princomp(x = scale(mtcars))

Standard deviations:
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5    Comp.6    Comp.7    Comp.8 
2.5301952 1.6023860 0.7794853 0.5110504 0.4652615 0.4527513 0.3619876 0.3450518 
   Comp.9   Comp.10   Comp.11 
0.2732013 0.2245202 0.1461353 

 11  variables and  32 observations.
> princomp(covmat = cor(scale(mtcars)))
Call:
princomp(covmat = cor(scale(mtcars)))

Standard deviations:
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5    Comp.6    Comp.7    Comp.8 
2.5706809 1.6280258 0.7919579 0.5192277 0.4727061 0.4599958 0.3677798 0.3505730 
   Comp.9   Comp.10   Comp.11 
0.2775728 0.2281128 0.1484736 

 11  variables and  NA observations.
> princomp(cor(scale(mtcars)))
Call:
princomp(x = cor(scale(mtcars)))

Standard deviations:
     Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3      Comp.4      Comp.5      Comp.6 
1.992444019 0.762563719 0.164481730 0.079889308 0.065557778 0.052541093 
     Comp.7      Comp.8      Comp.9     Comp.10     Comp.11 
0.040670837 0.024829720 0.022722621 0.006649006 0.000000000 

 11  variables and  11 observations.
```
````

Comment: Almost all of those "learn data science" websites are riddled with errors and inaccuracies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If some online tutorial disagrees with the official documentation of the software, almost always you should trust the documentation. What the documentation says is:

  > ## Description
  >
  > `princomp` performs a principal components analysis on the given numeric
  > data matrix and returns the results as an object of class `princomp`.
  >
  > ## Usage
  >
  > ```
  > princomp(x, ...)
  >
  > ## S3 method for class 'formula'
  > princomp(formula, data = NULL, subset, na.action, ...)
  >
  > ## Default S3 method:
  > princomp(x, cor = FALSE, scores = TRUE, covmat = NULL,
  >          subset = rep_len(TRUE, nrow(as.matrix(x))), fix_sign = TRUE, ...)
  >
  > ## S3 method for class 'princomp'
  > predict(object, newdata, ...)
  > ```
  >
  > ## Arguments
  >
  > `formula` a formula with no response variable, referring only to numeric
  > variables.
  >
  > `data` an optional data frame (or similar: see `model.frame`) containing the
  > variables in the `formula` formula. By default the variables are taken
  > from `environment(formula)`.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > `x` a numeric matrix or data frame which provides the data for the
  > principal components analysis.
  >
  > `cor` a logical value indicating whether the calculation should use the
  > correlation matrix or the covariance matrix. (The correlation matrix
  > can only be used if there are no constant variables.)
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > `covmat` a covariance matrix, or a covariance list as returned by `cov.wt` (and
  > `cov.mve` or `cov.mcd` from package MASS). If supplied, this is used
  > rather than the covariance matrix of x.
  >
  > [...]

  So it can be called either with raw data or the given covariance or correlation matrix (with `cor=TRUE`).
- The tutorial calculates the principal components analysis *of the correlation matrix*. Sure, you can do this, but in most cases, you would be interested in doing PCA of the raw data, rather than the correlation matrix.
- The tutorial uses the correlation matrix without the argument `cor=TRUE`. This makes sense if the author wants a PCA of the correlation matrix used as data, but is incorrect if they mean providing the correlation matrix (the `covmat` argument).
- The tutorial incorrectly suggests that you should scale the data before calculating the correlations. [This is not needed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602335/scaling-data-for-correlation-test), as correlation already is a *normalized* covariance.

So the moral is that you should not trust everything you read on the internet.